# How to use Django Signals to run a function after user registration completed?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-signals

I'm using [django_registration_redux](http://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package to handle registering new users. Then I have a set of categories, which I want each new user to follow them by default. So I have to run following code immediately after a user object created:

```
for category in categories:
    f = Follow(user=user.username, category=category)
    f.save()
```

After reading django Docs, I guessed that adding following method to the `UserProfile` model would work:

```
def follow_def_cat(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        for category in categories:
            f = Follow(user=instance.username, category=category)
            f.save()
    post_save.connect(follow_def_cat, sender=User)
```

But it seems I couldn't connect saving user signal to the function.

Comment: Is that your actual indentation?

Comment: Spelling mistake in post_save.connect

Comment: I've corrected the typo, but the problem caused from indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your connect instruction out of the signal method.

```
def follow_def_cat(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        for category in categories:
            f = Follow(user=instance.username, category=category)
            f.save()

post_save.connetc(follow_def_cat, sender=User)
```

And remember that `follow_def_cat` is not a model method, you should create it at the same level that the model class:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    ...

def follow_def_cat(sender, ...):
    ...

post_save.connect(follow_def_cat, sender=User)
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass the function `follow_def_cat' any arguments ??

Comment: @RohitKumar You can pass any argument by a named argument since it accepts `**kwargs`